Has there been any update in Google Maps Android SDK, version 18.2.0, wherein they have updated the view hierarchy of MapFragment?
I have a library written by myself in which I have been using Google Maps Android SDK version 18.1.0. I have two Android Apps with me, let's call them App1 and App2. And let's call my library Lib1.
I have written code in Lib1 to reposition the "my current location" button in the MapFragment to the bottom right corner of the screen (for the code, kindly check the initMapView() method below.
Everything was working fine, until I updated the Google Maps SDK version from 18.1.0 to 18.2.0. After this, whenever I try to open the screen having the MapFragment for the first time, the app crashes. The mystery lies in the fact that this happens only in App1, and not in App2, even though both the apps consume the same library code. It is also to be noted that the crash occurs only once, when I open the particular screen for the first time. It does not happen again.
I will provide the skeleton of the activity code.
In Lib1, I have an Activity called Activity1.kt, whose skeleton is as follows:
abstract class Activity1 : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = Activity1Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mBinding.root)
        
        /*other initialisations*/

        initMapView()
}

private fun initMapView()
{
        val mapFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment) as MapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

        /*This is where the crash occurs*/
        val locationButton = (mapFragment.view?.findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("1"))?.parent as View).findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("2"))

        val rlp =  locationButton.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0)
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE)
        rlp.setMargins(0, 0, 30, 30)
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap)
{
    mapObj = googleMap
    /*Other view initialisations*/
}

I have Activity2 in App1 which extends the abstract class Activity1 and implements its member functions.
class Activity2 : Activity1()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    /* Implementation of methods of abstract class Activity1 */
}

I have an abstract class Activity3 in Lib1 which is responsible for the UI.
public abstract class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public abstract void method1(View view);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity3_layout);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public void method2(View view)
    {
        method1(view);
    }
}

The layout file activity3_layout.xml looks like this:
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="method2"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:focusable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:onClick="method2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/string1"
            android:focusable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

Now, in App1, I have Activity4:
public class Activity4 extends Activity3
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        /* other necessary initialisations*/
    }

    //implementation of method1 of Activity3
    public void method1(View view)
    { 
        method3();
    }

    private void method3()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }       
}

In App1, when Activity4 is loaded, and when I click on linearLayout1, method2 is invoked, which in turn has an Intent to Activity2 which implements the abstract class Activity1. On calling the super.onCreate() method of Activity2, the onCreate() method of Activity1 is called, and ultimately, initMapView() method is called.
The crash occurs here, in this line:
val locationButton = (mapFragment.view?.findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("1"))?.parent as View).findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("2"))
The following is the crash logs:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app1/com.example.mymapap.ui.Activity5}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4126)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeNonLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:195)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:157)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:90)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2544)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
    at com.example.lib1.activity.Activity1.initMapView(Activity1.java:187)
    at com.example.lib1.activity.Activity1.onCreate(Activity1.java:98)
    at com.example.mymapapp.ui.Activity5.onCreate(Activity5.java:34)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8767)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8745)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1519)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3928)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4126)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeNonLifecycleItem(TransactionExecutor.java:195)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:157)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:90)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2544)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8501)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myProject.myActivity/com.myApp.main.ui.myAppMapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.View
What I tried?
Everything was working perfectly fine when the Google Maps Android SDK version was 18.1.0. Hence, in order to compare and inspect the view hierarchy of MapFragment in both versions(v18.1.0 and v18.2.0), I printed logs, wherein I printed the view type and its view Id of every view and its child. Here is the logs:
FrameLayout ID: 2131364778
  FrameLayout ID: -1
    ezq ID: -1
    RelativeLayout ID: -1
      ImageView ID: -1
      TextView ID: -1
    RelativeLayout ID: -1
      ImageView ID: 4            //Usually this would be 2
      RelativeLayout ID: 5       //Usually this would be 3
         dl ID: -1
      LinearLayout ID: 3         //Usually this would be 1
        ImageView ID: -1
        ImageView ID: -1
      LinearLayout ID: 6         //Usually this would be 4
        ImageView ID: -1
        ImageView ID: -1
      ay ID: 7
    RelativeLayout ID: -1
      RelativeLayout ID: -1
        ImageView ID: 8
        TextView ID: 9

Hence I tried changing the code to as follows, and it worked for me:
val myLocationButton = (mapFragment.view?.findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("3"))?.parent as View).findViewById<View>(Integer.parseInt("4"))
While this works for me in App1, I am unable to reproduce the same crash in App2. I have used the same kind of classes in App2 as I have used in App1 to load the MapFragment. I want to understand why the crash is happening only in App1 and not in App2, when I am using the same activity from my library. I am looking to find a solution to fix this issue.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend that you read through how to ask and how to provide a minimal reproducible example to increase your chances of getting help. With that said, can you show the full stack trace of the exception? It would help us determine whether the issue is because of something you wrote or because of some Android update, or because of an update from the Maps SDK itself.

@Yrll I have edited the post. Kindly check it out, and do let me know if there's anything else I can furnish you with.
